# Showing an integer with Month Calendar in C#

Tags: c#, database, integer, monthcalendar

I'm a beginner to the the programming language C#. What I'm wondering is that is it possible to **display a specific date using the MonthCalendar** in C# Visual Studios instead of using it to read inputs from the user?

I already know how to read the value from my database, but what I'm not sure of is what kind of syntax or format the lines for MonthCalendar should use.

*The date I have is stored as DateTime in my database.*

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Edit: These are some of the codes that were typed in:**

*From the **Class** 'Technician'*

```
req.Collect = Convert.ToDateTime(rd.["Collect_Date"]);
```

*In the **form itself***

```
mthCalCompletionDate.SelectionStart = DateTime.Parse(req.Collect.ToString());
  
mthCalCompletionDate.SelectionEnd = DateTime.Parse(req.Collect.ToString());
```

*However Error code shows **'Indentifier Expected'** for*
req.Collect = Convert.ToDateTime(rd.**[**"Collect_Date"**]**);

Comment: In general, you can use the calendar for read and write. In case you want the user to only read a value, you can look for 2 properties of the MonthCalendar; ReadOnly and Disabled. 
By setting any of the properties to true, you will make the MonthCalendar non editable.

Comment: I think you are looking for DateTime class that can be parsed from the integer in your db, also allows you to take the Month , year day etc. With the tostring method of the object you can specify date format for example d.toString("yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: *"The date I have is stored as an integer in my database."* Do you mean to tell me that today is stored as an integer `20211109`?? Why would you do that, and not use a `date` or `datetime` column

Comment: lmao you're right, that makes more sense. Edited the column to a more sensible DateTime instead

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the good advice in the comments, I believe the problem at hand is that you've got a `.` in your code:

```cs
req.Collect = Convert.ToDateTime(rd.["Collect_Date"]);
                                   ^
```

It should be like this:

```cs
req.Collect = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["Collect_Date"]);
                                  ^^
```

Comment: ahh you're right, much thanks for pointing it out!